# Need a bootable OS X installer iso

Tags: macos, startup

I removed the OS X partition off my HDD and installed Ubuntu. Now I want OS X back but I can't install it considering I have no access to Mac OS X. I need either an OS X Snow Leopard or OS X Lion .iso so I can put it on an installer USB.

Comment: you mean if you hold cmd+r it doesn't go back to recovery mode? Also, we need what model your machine is. if you could edit your question to reflect this, that would be greatly appreciated. Be sure to see [How to Ask](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: It won't work... I have tried...

Comment: Please add the system you are running to the question, It will help us identify possible solutions. also, depending on the system you have, you will be able to boot into internet recovery. to do this, press Command (⌘) – Option (⌥) – R. If this does not work, press the option key on boot to list all available partitions on the drive. It should contain a recovery partition depending on what system you have.

Comment: Please please please add the model of your system.

Comment: @bret7600: Early 2008 Macbook (MacBook 4,1) which is to old to work with internet recovery.

Comment: Your simplest fix is going to be to take it to an Apple Store. They will push a new OS to it, usually for free. Torrenting an iso [actually you want a dmg] is a) very hit & miss, security-wise & b) requires another machine to burn to disk. USB is a no-no on a machine that old.

Answer (score 3):

Since OS X Lion was around $30 USD on release you definitely, *definitely* wouldn't want to torrent the .iso. I would image you could find the torrent fairly easily if you were to look. But you wouldn't do that, would you, because that would be immoral and possibly illegal in your area.

Comment: It is also against Apples TOS

Comment: Doesn't Lion require Snow Leopard to be installed first? See: [OS X Lion (10.7)](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/D6106Z/A/os-x-lion)

Comment: Nahhhhh... I wouldn't wanna torrent. I did buy it legally when it came out but I can't access it considering it's in the Mac App Store. I really need an ISO though...

Answer (score 3):

Apple still sells Snow Leopard 10.6.3 install disks for $20 US, shipping included.  That's probably your least annoying, least dodgy/insecure recourse for getting Mac OS back onto your Mac.

Even if you decide you don't want to use OS X ever again, it's a good idea to keep a small Mac OS partition on the hard drive - for one thing, the Mac system settings app is the only way to change certain hardware settings such as "resume after power failure." It's pretty straightforward to shrink the partition down to around 10 gb, which isn't too much space to sacrifice for the safety net it provides.

Comment: The online store ([here](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MC573Z/A/mac-os-x-106-snow-leopard)) is quoting about a month to deliver the installer DVD -- I'm not sure I really trust their availability.

Answer (score 3):

Mac OS X 10.5 Leopard installer download link:
https://archive.org/details/OsxLeopardInstall

Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard installer download link:
https://archive.org/details/SnowLeopardInstall

Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard Server installer download link:
https://archive.org/details/SnowLeopardServer

Note: Archive.org is a legitimate, non-profit site which keeps archival copies of various websites, software, and media for historical and educational purposes.