# Mid 2009 MacBook pro cannot download osx

Tags: macbook-pro

I have a mid-2009 MacBook pro in which I replaced the
HD with SSHD a few years ago. It was updated to El
Capitan and runs fine. Now I want to get it ready to sell. I have successfully erased the SSHD but cannot get OS X of any version to download.  I have tried the original OS X CD, snow leopard
CD, internet downloads, all to no success.  When running from the disk drive it will start through the process and stall out.  Via internet it also starts through the process and stops, I get a message that it could not be installed and "no packages are eligible for install" I can restore it via time machine and have done so and restarted the process per Apple instructions but cannot get it to work. Help.

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos/309400#309400

Answer (score 0):

As you have the Snow Leopard disk, you can use another mac with an optical drive to create a bootable USB installer by following the answer to this question [How to create a bootable OS X Snow Leopard USB drive?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/400472/how-to-create-a-bootable-os-x-snow-leopard-usb-drive/400475#400475) and using the Snow Leopard install disc instead of the iso file that is mentioned in the answer.

If you don't have another mac with an optical drive, you can either use the Snow Leopard install disc in a PC with optical drive to create an iso image, or download an existing iso image by following this answer: [macOS won't boot into Recovery mode, need to reset admin password](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/363738/macos-wont-boot-into-recovery-mode-need-to-reset-admin-password/363745#363745), and use it in the process outlined in the answer linked in the first paragraph to create a bootable USB installer.

Plug the bootable USB media into the 2009 Mac, reboot it while holding down the option key and select the USB device.