# Cliffhanger while attempting to setup Snow Leopard in Fusion

Tags: snow-leopard, vmware

I'm following the instructions in [this article](https://left404.com/2020/04/17/installing-snow-leopard-in-vmware-fusion/), "Installing Snow Leopard in VMware Fusion", to create a Snow Leopard virtual machine.

I downloaded the ISO from https://archive.org/details/snow-leopard-install_202112.

I used [EFI Unlocker](https://github.com/ivanagui2/efi-unlocker) to create the two ROM files per the above instructions. I copied the ROM files to the "Snow Leopard" VMBundle, and while it was open I added the needed lines to the .VMX file.

But when I reopen Fusion and start the VM to begin setup from the ISO an error message soon appears:  "Could not open EFI64-MACOS.ROM (No such file or directory)" . Actually that error appears twice, then setup closes.

Any suggestions about how to overcome this?

Comment: What is your host machine? VirtualBox will allow Snow Leopard installations without having to do the modifications given in your linked article.

Comment: mid-2012 MacBook Pro, i7.   "Wow!" about VirtualBox. I'll give it a try if it can coexist with Fusion.  This problem with Snow Leopard was a surprise because I was able to create VMs for most if not all of the MacOS's since Mtn. Lion on this MBP.  (so I can support people with different versions)  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: VirtualBox can coexist with Fusion Player. I have both installed on a 2013 iMac running Catalina (with 16 GB of memory). I used the Snow Leopard ISO from [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/363738/os-x-snow-leopard-wont-boot-into-recovery-mode-need-to-reset-admin-password/363745#363745).

Comment: 1) Suggest you read https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/installing-snow-leopard-and-rosetta-into-parallels-7-in-lion.1365439/ It is primarily about SL in Parallels, but the thread contains instructions (some by me) regarding similar method for SL in Fusion. 2) Can you get hold of SL Server?