# Issue reading removable drive during macOS install

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

I have a MacBook Pro (15", Core 2 Duo), model A1226, and I am trying to install macOS on this MacBook, but when I tried, my laptop can not see my bootable pendrive. The last disk does not work, as it is damaged. So what can I do?

I tried install on TransMac.

Comment: Generally, more information is needed to revolve the issue. It would be helpful to know which version of macOS you are attempting to install, as well as what sort of removable drive you are using. I would also suggest running [Apple Hardware Test](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257) and updating your question with the result.

Answer (score 1):

According to [everyman.com](https://everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/?search_keywords=a1226), you mac appears to be a mid/late 2007 model.

The Pre-Installed operating system was OS X 10.4.9 (8Q1058) (Tiger). The Maximum operating system is OS X 10.11.6 (El Capitan).

If you are using TransMac, I assume you have a DMG file. You can use DMG files to upgrade OS X, but you can not use a DMG file to do an clean install of OS X. For example, if you purchase Lion from Apple, then you must first have Snow Leopard installed in order to use the purchased file to upgrade to Lion.

Apple still [sells Snow Leopard DVDs](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MC573Z/A/mac-os-x-106-snow-leopard), but you can also [download an ISO](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/354170/2nd-hand-imac-with-no-os/354187#354187) from the internet. There are plenty of websites that explain how to make a bootable USB Snow Leopard installer. I have not tried any of these methods. If you succeed, then maybe you could post a method that works.

> I would recommend burning the Snow Leopard ISO file to a DL DVD.

Once you have Snow Leopard installed, you should install all the available [Snow Leopard updates](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1399?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US). This would update Snow Leopard to OS X 10.6.8.

Once Snow Leopard OS X 10.6.8 is installed, you can upgrade to El Capitan for free.
Enter this address: https://itunes.apple.com/app/os-x-el-capitan/id1147835434?mt=12 into Safari on the Mac running Snow Leopard. You should be able to download El Capitan. Follow the instructions at https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372 to create a bootable USB El Capitan installer.

Please post of comment, if you needed an Apple Id to download El Capitan.